# Avoid or prevent Lead edition when status is "Qualified"

Tags: validation-rule, leads, lead-conversion

I have the next requirement: When users set lead to 'Qualified', **I want a way to prevent them to editing any field**.

I've tried some things like validation rules like this:

```java
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status),"Qualified")
```

This works fine unitl a user tries to **convert it**, the validation rule takes action and does not allow him to finish the conversion (I think is because in background the lead is chaging its status to 'closed').

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not clear on your goal. You want to prevent edits to lead with a status of "qualified", but you don't want it to run when it's a conversion?

Comment: This is because I want to force users to convert each lead when their status is 'qualified'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to not have the validation rule trigger on lead conversion, I'd add a check on the isConverted field on lead. This would only run when that field is false and a lead isn't converted.

```
AND(
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status),"Qualified),
IsConverted = FALSE
)
```